# Set mail recipients when using UIActivityViewController iOS 8

Tags: swift, email, ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I would like to know if there is a simplified method of setting the mail recipients when using UIActivityViewController with iOS 8? I want to add the mail recipients. I was trying to do so using the following code but the recipient is just added to the main body of text.

```
     let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(fileName)
     let url2 = NSURL(string: "mailto:somebody@gmail.com") as! AnyObject
     let activityItems:Array = [url, url2]
     let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems , applicationActivities: nil)
```

I have seen some workaround methods for iOS 6 but just wondered if there was now a simplified method to add the recipient?

Comment: could you find a solution on this?